# Passing parameter in URL along with previous parameter

Tags: php, redirect

I have searching functionality working with GET, like if I search for 'Apple', it will redirect to this particular `URL: /search.php?search=Apple`.
Now if I add this product in cart, it will go to addtocart.php file & should redirect to the current page. In addtocart.php file I've code like this, if everything goes fine, it should go to this `URL: $page?message=Product has been added to your cart`. Now the issue is as two '?' comes in URL, it doesn't display message on the first place & doesn't display the page with search results.
For finding the current page URL, I've this code.

```
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$page=(stristr($page,"/"));
$_SESSION['page'] = $page;
```

In addtocart.php file, I get the value of $page redirect to the same page after adding the product in cart.
So I've this code for redirecting:

```
header ("Location: $page?message=Product added to your cart");
```

So ultimately URL that it redirects to looks like: `search.php?search=apple?message=Product added to your cart`. And it doesn't actually pass the parameter & hence no searching can be done. Anything that I missed and you can help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a second parameter you need to use `&` instead of the second `?`.

The header path would then be:

```
 header ("Location: $page&message=Product added to your cart");
```

If you might have some paths that don't include an initial value you can check for the presence of the the `?` and then alter the appending character.

E.g.

```
<?php if(preg_match('/\?/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { $page .= '&'; }
      else{ $page .= '?'; }
    $page .= "message=Product added to your cart";
   header ("Location: $page");
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing? Let's say I have this URL: www.example.com/veg.php?sub_cat=33&message=Productaddedtoyourcart. How would I get only this URL: /veg.php?sub_cat=32? It's because next time if a person tries to add the same product again, it gives him warning, & URL becaomes www.example.com/veg.php?sub_cat=33&message=Productaddedtoyourcart&message=ProductAlreadyExists. So ultimately it's printing twice.

Comment: You can get the `veg.php?sub_cat=33&message=Productaddedtoyourcart&message=Produc‌​tAlreadyExists` string with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header ("Location: $page&message=Product added to your cart");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$delimiter = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY) ? '&' : '?';
header("Location: {$page}{$delimiter}message=$message");
```

Also, you can use `strrpos($url, '?') !== false` instead of `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY) === ''`.